# create Executable file from Console Application

Tags: c#-4.0, console-application, exe

I am trying to create executable file from console application. 
I tried copying the application.exe file from the projectname/bin/release folder and run it. 
On run, getting the error 
unhandled exception system.io.filenotfoundexception Could not load assembly Version 1.1.1.1 culture neutral PublicKeyToken = null' ...

In the project, I have kept some repeating codes in db.dll which I have myself created. Please advise.

Is this the proper way to create Executable file from Console Application?

Comment: Well, you did not copy enough.  Copy the DLL files as well.

Comment: U mean where I run the .exe file, I should have the .dll in same folder location?